# ADO, Adonis, Update Criteria

Tags: delphi, ado

On a form, I have a Quantum Grid and some db-aware editcomponents. When appending a new record in the grid, typing some editvalues both in the grid and the separate editcompoennts, I get an error:

> EOleException: Row cannot be located for updating. Some values may have been chenged since it was last read

After some googling, I think changing the 'Update Criteria'-property from  adCriteriaAllCols to adCriteriaKey may be the right solution. But how, and when, do I do that on a Adonis query?

Answer (score 1):

if your dataset contains an autoincrement field or one or more fields have default values then this may be the problem. After calling Post fields change their value in the db but that may not be detected by your dataset

Comment: That may have been the problem. The code was rewritten a long time ago, though, to get rid of any direct data binding and problems like this one.

Answer (score 0):

Although I don't use Adonis, I believe there is a possibility it use the same mechanism TClientDataset (CDS) uses to identify the fields that compose the primary key: the property ***TField.ProviderFlags***.

I believe it could be a good place to start looking.

Comment: Actually, all the dbcomponents are thrown away now. Recreated the gui using regular components, made a middleware with objects, and handling the object to database transition - It sure was faster than messing with adonis...

Comment: Actually, I use clientdatasets for everything... And since Andreas (Andreas Hausladen) got a speed up for them, things are even better.

Answer (score 0):

Actually ADO provides [dynamic property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680933%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to control Query Based Update (QBU) behavior
Most of code is covered in ADOInt.pas, the appropriate event is OnAfterOpen for recordset properties (any TADODataSet), and OnCreate for connection properties (TADOConnection).
I guess ‘Update Criteria’ is not the solution in this case, since it deals with WHERE clause to specify fields to be used for updates.
You may change 'Update Resync' as follows:

```
//After open a TCustomADODataSet
  TCustomADODataSet(DataSet).Properties['Update Resync'].Value :=
    adResyncAutoIncrement + adResyncUpdates + adResyncInserts;
```

Answer (score 0):

if you have join table in your query :

TADOQuery cannot be edit and post data in sql database.

you can create other TADOQuery and select by primary key without any join table and edit and then post data in sql database.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem - Updating a row where all values were the same would result in the error you're getting. I added the flag "Option=2" to the end of my ado connection and this fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

This is old. but my situation may happens for someone else. so I post this answer.

This Error happened for me too.
I was using Access database and using some TADOTable on the form.
the relation was master-detail and I connected all of the tables with the IDE Designer together.
my tables were tbl_Floor,tbl_FloorParts,tbl_Seat which tbl_Floor was master of tbl_FloorParts and tbl_FloorParts was master of tbl_Seat.
So for solving this error I did this trick.

```
procedure Tfrm_Main.UpdateTblFloor(...);
var
  FID:Integer;
  q:TADOQuery
begin
  FID:=tbl_Floor.FieldByName('FID').AsInteger;
  tbl_Floor.Close;
  q:=TADOQuery.Create(nil);
  try
    q.Connection:=tbl_Floor.Connection;
    q.SQL.Add('Update [Floor]');
    q.SQL.Add(...);//Set Fields that needed to be updated
    q.SQL.Add('where [FID]='+IntToStr(FID));
    q.ExecSQL;  
  finally
    q.free;
  end;
  tbl_Floor.Open;
  tbl_Floor.Locate('FID',FId,[loPartialKey]);
end;
```

and I added these events for tbl_Floor,tbl_FloorParts

```
procedure Tfrm_Main.tbl_FloorAfterOpen(DataSet: TDataSet);
begin
  tbl_FloorParts.Open;
end;

procedure Tfrm_Main.tbl_FloorBeforeClose(DataSet: TDataSet);
begin
  tbl_FloorParts.Close;
end;

procedure Tfrm_Main.tbl_FloorPartsAfterOpen(DataSet: TDataSet);
begin
  tbl_Seat.Open;
end;

procedure Tfrm_Main.tbl_FloorPartsBeforeClose(DataSet: TDataSet);
begin
  tbl_Seat.Close;
end;
```

Comment: Calling tbl_Floor.Edit immediately after closing it makes no sense (nor does calling .Post immediately before calling .Open).  Please do not post fake code, it is no help to anybody.  Meanwhile, -1.

Comment: @ MartynA. sorry. you are right. I updated that with query. I just wanted to not right the whole code and made such foolish mistake. thanks for your comment.

Comment: The solution you posted seems possible however I would suggest to use adoquery.cursorLocation:=clUseServer for the queries. Although I do not know Adonis, the question that is posted here may be solved with this approach (i.e. changing cursor location to server side). Also double-check if your table has a primary key.